# VB.Net SpecialFolder.ApplicationData not working

Tags: vb.net, settings, auto-update

Im working on a update checker settings that you can enable and disable.
If you enable the settings there will be a file created called "UA.set"
Now I combined my update check messages with a code that will check if the file UA.set file exist but I doesnt work...
Can you maby help me with this problem?

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\MozarCodes\DuckyTool2\Settings"
    Dim objFSO, strFile
    strFile = "filePath\UA.set"
    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
        Dim url As New System.Uri("http://mozarcodes.netne.net/DT2-1/")
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
        req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse
        Try
            resp = req.GetResponse()
            resp.Close()
            req = Nothing
            MsgBox("Update Found! Please update to our latest version on http://mozarcodes.netne.net/")
        Catch ex As Exception
            req = Nothing
            MsgBox("You are now using the latest version of DuckyTool 2!")
        End Try
    End If
    Threading.Thread.Sleep("1")
End Sub
```

Thank you very much! (Ill give credits on my site if you found a solution :D)

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the problem?

Comment: If the file doesnt exists it will still give me the MsgBox

Comment: _strFile = "filePath\UA.set"_ are you sure that this is not just _strFile = filePath & "UA.set"_

Comment: in the code there stands `strFile = "filePath\UA.set"` but I tryd `strFile = filePath & "UA.set"` but it didnt work.

Comment: I forgot to add the backslash in the comment, look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing for an inexistant file with this line

```
strFile = "filePath\UA.set"
```

The correct code should be

```
filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\MozarCodes\DuckyTool2\Settings"
Dim objFSO, strFile
strFile = filePath & "\UA.set"
```

By the way, please discard the old VB6/VBA objects like the Scripting.FileSystemObject and use the classes and methods of the NET Framework

```
If Not File.Exists(strFile) Then
```

Comment: Thank you this solution helped me :D!